# Uninstall String Rededit

Tags: java, registry, windows-server-2008-r2, uninstallation

I am using Windows 2008R2 Core OS and am wanting to uninstall Java.  I found the uninstall URL in regedit in the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

This ran through the uninstall wizard and all seemed fine.  I checked Add\Remove programs again though and Java is still listed.  I searched the registry and found another entry in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Products
```

There is a Uninstall URL in there too but this is failing with an error of:

```
Bad numeric constant:
```

Does anyone know what my nexts steps should be?

Comment: how you are uninstalling Java from that registry URL ? 
   
If you just want to uninstall Java, then go to Control Panel -> Add/Remove program -> Find Java there and right click & say uninstall.  

And registry for Java is present at 
For 64 bit Java : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft
For 32 bit Java : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft

Comment: You can't do that as its windows core as mentioned.

Comment: Sorry !! It was my mistake !!

Comment: The way I checked add\remove programs is through a powershell command